# sorting alg error no match for call to

Tags: c++

Im trying get this program to work but i cant figure out whats wrong with this error.

I have these 5 files, im getting the error in candidateType.cpp

candidatetype.h

```
#ifndef H_candidateType
#define H_candidateType

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "personType.h"

const int NO_OF_REGIONS = 4;

class candidateType: public personType
{
public:
      const candidateType& operator=(const candidateType&);

      const candidateType& operator=(const personType&);

      void updateVotesByRegion(int region, int votes);

      void setVotes(int region, int votes);

      void calculateTotalVotes();

      int getTotalVotes() const;

      void printData() const;

      candidateType();

       bool operator==(const candidateType& right) const;
       bool operator!=(const candidateType& right) const;
       bool operator<=(const candidateType& right) const;
       bool operator<(const candidateType& right) const;
       bool operator>=(const candidateType& right) const;
       bool operator>(const candidateType& right) const;

private:
        int votesByRegion[NO_OF_REGIONS];

        int totalVotes;
};
#endif
```

candidatetype.cpp

```
#include "candidateType.h"

void candidateType::setVotes(int region, int votes)
{
    votesByRegion[region - 1] = votes;
}

void candidateType::updateVotesByRegion(int region, int votes)
{
    votesByRegion[region - 1] = votesByRegion[region - 1] + votes;
}

void candidateType::calculateTotalVotes()
{
    int i;

    totalVotes = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < NO_OF_REGIONS; i++)
        totalVotes += votesByRegion[i];
}

int candidateType::getTotalVotes() const
{
    return totalVotes;
}

void candidateType::printData() const
{
    cout << left
        << setw(8) << firstName << " "
        << setw(8) << lastName << " ";

    cout << right;
    for (int i = 0; i < NO_OF_REGIONS; i++)
        cout << setw(8) << votesByRegion[i] << " ";
        cout << setw(7) << totalVotes << endl;
}

candidateType::candidateType()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NO_OF_REGIONS; i++)
        votesByRegion[i] = 0;

    totalVotes = 0;
}

bool candidateType::operator==(const candidateType& right) const
{
    return (firstName == right.firstName && lastName == right.lastName);
}

bool candidateType::operator!=(const candidateType& right) const
{
    return (firstName != right.firstName || lastName != right.lastName);
}

bool candidateType::operator<=(const candidateType& right) const
{
    return (lastName <= right.lastName || (lastName == right.lastName
             && firstName <= right.firstName));
}

bool candidateType::operator<(const candidateType& right) const
{
    return (lastName < right.lastName || (lastName == right.lastName
             && firstName < right.firstName));
}

bool candidateType::operator>=(const candidateType& right) const
{
    return (lastName >= right.lastName || (lastName == right.lastName
             && firstName >= right.firstName));
}

bool candidateType::operator>(const candidateType& right) const
{
    return (lastName > right.lastName || (lastName == right.lastName
             && firstName > right.firstName));
}

const candidateType& candidateType::operator=(const candidateType& right)
{
    if (this != &right)
    {
        firstName = right.firstName;
        lastName = right.lastName;

        for (int i = 0; i < NO_OF_REGIONS; i++)
            votesByRegion[i] = right.votesByRegion[i];

        totalVotes = right.totalVotes;
      }

    return *this;
}

const candidateType& candidateType::operator=(const personType& right)
{
    firstName = right.getFirstName();
    lastName = right.getLastName();

    return *this;
}
```

in member function void candidateType::printData() const
|31|error: 'setw' was not declared in this scope|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Comment: Ever hear of `namespaces`?

Comment: You may want to include `iomanip`, it's a standard library include file.

Comment: Another thing is that you're defining all of your logical operators from scratch unnecessarily. For example, all you need is to define `operator <` and `operator ==` "fully", and then all of the other operators are coded in terms of those operators. For example `operator !=` can be simply `return !(*this == candidate);`

Comment: @user3605922 To continue:  `operator<=` can be simply `return *this < candidate || *this == candidate;`  You can derive the other operations using this technique.  This not only makes the code easier to understand, you're not doing all sorts of contortions figuring out how to reverse all of the nots, ands, or's, etc. thus possibly introducing bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include header `<iomanip>` and use nested name `std::setw`

Answer (score 1):

```
 'setw' was not declared
```

means that you are lacking a declaration of `setw`. It is defined in namespace `std` and presented in `<iomanip>` header. So just include this one and wrap a usage of setw with

```
std::setw
```